# alfresco bulk upload of images with metadata in xml

Tags: javascript, xml, alfresco-share

Am very new to alfresco and I am tasked to upload alot of images with their respective metadata. The metadata is in xml format. For example the first batch have 10,000 files with the following naming, for the image is a imagename.Tiff(employee1.tiff,employee2.tiff etc), the xml contains metadata of the employee e.g employee no,name, department, date employeed etc. I have created custom aspects that corresponds to the metadata but my problem is how to index the metadata into alfresco.
I have already created a listening folder where when i drop my files thy are been picked and placed in the right space. The remaining issue is to index the metadata for each uploaded image.

Kindly assist.

Answer (score 0):

An easy way to ingest in bulk, with metadata, is to use [Alfresco's Bulk Import Tool](http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/index.jsp?topic=/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/Bulk-Import-Tool.html)

If you are on Alfresco Enterprise, then I recommend that you use the In-place Bulk Import.  However, if you do use the In-place Bulk Import, you'll want to distribute the files efficiently on the filesystem and also keep children limited to a few thousand as recommended by Alfresco.

Regarding the metadata in XML - you'll need to transform the XML into the format the tool is looking for.  Details available here: http://docs.alfresco.com/4.2/topic/com.alfresco.enterprise.doc/concepts/bulk-import-prepare-filesystem.html

Comment: Please don't use the embedded fork, as it's outdated, buggy and slow.  The original edition of the tool is a better alternative, and is available here: https://github.com/pmonks/alfresco-bulk-import